# Pulling Null date (Microsoft SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I'm a little new to the site and have been teaching myself Microsoft SQL over the past week to cover for work and was hoping you guys could help. I have to pull all active patients for a type of group and the only way to tell if patients are active is if there is not a date discharge for the patient. My code is the following.

```
select
p.clinic_id,
p.program_id,
p.protocol_id,
p.patient_id,
p.date_discharged
from patient_assignment p
where p.program_id = 'MH'
and p.protocol_id = 'grp'
and p.date_discharged IS NULL
```

(Have also tried date_discharge = 'Null') - It enter code here`works without this line.

It is not pulling in any information when I view the field I see there are null values.

I'm sure this is something simple. I am just very green with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The column is called `p.date_discharged` you are missing a d at the end.

Comment: it happens..upvoted to counter the down votes..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `p.date_discharged IS NULL` you've aliased your table name, and used the alias `a` everywhere except there, as well as used the wrong column name.  The `invalid column name` was a good hint.

Comment: No go. It still pulls up no results. It doesn't error just doesn't pull anything.

Comment: Are you sure there are matching records?  Build up your query slowly.  Start with just `where p.date_discharged IS NULL` and see if that returns anything.  Also verify that there is a record in there matches all conditions.

Comment: I think I figured out what was going on by searching just null. It looks like the front end software switched
where p.program_id = 'MH'
and p.protocol_id = 'grp'

to 

where p.program_id = 'CSS'
and p.protocol_id = 'MH' 
about 2 years ago. I think I am good now. Just a case of me not knowing the system where I am not the SQL guy. Thanks!

Comment: It always helps to build a query slowly, especially when one is learning.  Add one clause at time, and work on a small test databse, if possible, so you can know exactly which records should be returned.

Comment: Thanks. It's funny, because I just ended up doing it backwards, because I added it one at a time, but added NULL last. Didn't realize they redid so much in the front end software with updates.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
select
p.clinic_id,
p.program_id,
p.protocol_id,
p.patient_id,
p.date_discharged
from patient_assignment p
where p.program_id = 'MH'
and p.protocol_id = 'grp'
and date_discharged IS NULL
```

You missed date_discharged with date_discharge.

Comment: someone is so happy with doing the unnecessary downvote. Looks good, question and answers all are down-voted :)

Comment: O sorry. I made a mistake recreating it. I was wondering why the error was different. With it like this I just get no results, but if I view the patient_assignment where I pulled it from there are null values in the date_discharged field. Sorry about that and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try **[ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)**

```
select
p.clinic_id,
p.program_id,
p.protocol_id,
p.patient_id,
p.date_discharged
from patient_assignment p
where p.program_id = 'MH'
and p.protocol_id = 'grp'
and ISNULL(p.date_discharged,'')=''
```